# Python child thread blocks parent thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a main thread that needs to run continuously, and it should create new processor threads for each data it receives and they should run continuously as well, but my problem is, that the main thread's run function runs only once, the child thread is blocking the while in the main thread's run.

```
import threading

threads = []

class MainThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    #some functions here

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print "main"
            #do some stuff
            data = ""
            client = Client()
            if data == "something":
                c = 0
                found = False
                while not found and c<len(threads):
                    if threads[c].client == client:
                        threads[c].doSomeStuff(data)
                        found = True
                    
                if not found:
                    DataHandler(data, client)

class DataHandler(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, data, client):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.data = data
            self.client = client
        global threads
        threads.append(self)
 
    def doSomeStuff(self, data):
        self.data = data
        #some IO and networking stuff
    
    #some functions here

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if data is not None:
                print "data"
            #do some stuff with data

MainThread().start()
```

my output is:

> main
>
> data
>
> data
>
> data
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .

How am I managed to start a `DataHandler` thread parallel with the `MainThread`?

Comment: does `somecondition` stays true for main thread once child thread is started ? Because as it is written the `while` loop will continuously call `start` on child thread. Also, it seems it is a busy loop eating 100% CPU because it runs continuously with no wait or sleep or I/O operation

Comment: it's changing according to data, it's just a simplified example

Comment: if your `DataHandler` consumes all CPU in a busy loop too, there is little chance for main thread to be executed... Put more realistic code so we can help. Otherwise it looks ok...

Answer (score 1):

Python `threading.Thread` is not a good choice for CPU intensive busy loops because of the GIL. According to https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

> the global interpreter lock, or GIL, is a mutex that prevents multiple
>   native threads from executing Python bytecodes at once. This lock is
>   necessary mainly because CPython's memory management is not
>   thread-safe.

If you need a busy loop, switch to the `thread.multiprocessing` stblib instead (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) to have the OS scheduler handle time slice allocation. From the docs

> The multiprocessing package offers both local and remote concurrency,
>   effectively side-stepping the Global Interpreter Lock by using
>   subprocesses instead of threads.

Comment: Looks helpful, but can I start a class as a process, and if it is already started, can I call it's functions?

Comment: If it is possible, then can you give me a little example of doing something like i explained with processes? I'd really appreciate it.